# How to generate a new MS access file programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have looked far and wide, in the deepest darkest corners of the internet, but for the life of me, I can not find the correct way to open a NEW Access file and then using vb.net to write data in the database..

The keywords here are NEW database, I don't want to open an existing file.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally found the way, thanks to a co-worker of mine

> Neither ADO.NET nor ActiveX Data Object (ADO) provides the means to create Microsoft
>   Access Database. However, we can create Access databases by using the Microsoft Jet OLE DB 
>   Provider and Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.7 for DDL and Security (ADOX) with the COM Interop 
>   layer. To do so, **select References from the Project Menu, choose the COM tab, and add a 
>   reference to Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.7 for DDL and Security**; then you can use this function.

When you have done this, use the following snippet to create a database

---

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                              Handles btnLoad.Click

        CreateAccessDatabase("C:\test\testDB.mdb")
        MsgBox("Database created")
    End Sub
```

---

```
    Public Function CreateAccessDatabase( ByVal DatabaseFullPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim bAns As Boolean
        Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog()
        Try

            Dim sCreateString As String
            sCreateString =_ 
                           "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                           DatabaseFullPath
            cat.Create(sCreateString)

             bAns = True

        Catch Excep As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
             bAns = False

        Finally
            cat = Nothing
        End Try
        Return bAns
    End Function
End Class
```

---