# How to create a new microsoft access database programmatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to create a new Microsoft access database if none is existing with tables programmatically in vb.net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a new MS access file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082071/how-to-generate-a-new-ms-access-file-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to accomplish this is to distribute an empty reference database as part of your application, with perhaps just the basic table structure already defined. Then *copy* the empty database to the desired location when you need to start using it.